# Websocket closing on Chromecast Receiver Application

Tags: javascript, chromecast

Hmm, so I thought not passing in NAMESPACE as an array, `[ NAMESPACE]` was my problem too ([see this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191114/chromecast-receiver-app-error-the-websocket-disconnected-unexpectedly-undefine)), but even after making sure the `Receiver` constructor took an array of NAMESPACE it doesn't seem to work. @dowski would love your help on this. Here's my javascript console output:

```
 [  0.102s] [cast.receiver.ChannelHandler] New channel factory added: YouTube to heartbeatChannelHandler
 cast_receiver.js:55

 [  0.108s] [cast.receiver.ChannelHandler] New channel factory added: com.google.chromecast.umano:YouTube to com.google.chromecast.umano
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.109s] [cast.receiver.ConnectionService] Open connection service websocket: url=ws://localhost:8008/connection
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.110s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/connection
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.111s] [cast.receiver.Receiver] Receiver started.
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.112s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.113s] [cast.receiver.ConnectionService] Got event: b
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.113s] [cast.receiver.ConnectionService] Close connection service websocket
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.113s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Closing the WebSocket.
 cast_receiver.js:55
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8008/connection' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. cast_receiver.js:33
 [  0.114s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/connection closed.
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.115s] [cast.receiver.ConnectionService] Got event: a
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [  0.115s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket closed normally.
```

Comment: You need to post your code.